How to ask for clarification multiple times without appearing to challenge?
Sometimes when someone is asked to clarify something, especially with "Why?", they might read the subtext as: "I disagree, and I challenge you to defend what you said!"
If it's a decision, they may think their judgement is being questioned, and if it's a statement of fact or opinion, they may think its credibility or validity is in doubt.
An example conversation might go something like this:

Arthika: Should we put the foo somewhere in the bar?
Bartók: Why's that?
Arthika: Well, remember baz?
Bartók: Yeah — that was the time when all the quxes happened.
Arthika: Right, so then we should put the foo in the bar?
Bartók: I'm not following the logic.
Arthika: If we take the foo, we could then put it in the bar.
Bartók: Sounds good, I'm not against that, but what's the link with baz? Sorry for being a bit slow...
Arthika: Never mind, it was just a question.

What are some things Bartók can do better in order to clearly communicate that he's interested and invested in understanding the reason for the suggested course of action, and not trying to poke holes in it?

In the example you give, Bartok sounds quite reasonable and makes efforts to be non-confrontational. As presented it sounds more like Arthika either doesn't have a reason or has decided it's not a good one. Maybe a real example would be clearer

@mattfreake Thanks, that's helpful. This is actually a real example, just with the specific decision and related event obscured. I wonder if Bartók would have a way of encouraging Arthika to share the reason in order to examine it even if it turns out not to be a good one, or if it's better to let it drop. (Not that I think this site is meant to answer the "what should I do" question, just observing that it's probably the next thing to think about assuming your reading is right.)

In the exchange you describe it sounds like Arthika is clamming up for some reason. If that happened I would not push it but say something like "It sound like you might have a good idea to prevent X. I'd be interested to hear it sometime". Then hopefully they will tell you at some point, maybe with a focus on how it prevents X

I'm a curious person with some room for improvement regarding my social skills and I've applied to following which works for me: Just explain how people might interpret it followed by how I mean it.

I have a question (or: some questions). I'd like to preface this with that I sometimes sound rude/harsh/disrespectful*, if I do please let me know, but it in fact comes from a place of interest. I'd like to understand things so I can discuss them with you better :)

That, or some variant of that. Both parts of that quote are important:

Highlight that you might sound confronting in a way, that that is your fault, and not the intention at all.
The last part is that you wish to improve your knownledge, not just for you but that this is a way to show interest in them

* Pick one you think might apply

Thanks. Though I won't get a chance to test this out just yet, I'll mark it accepted since it's been a few days and it seems like a good suggestion.

This is a good answer, but to me it seems to apply only in situations where Bartok barely know the other person. You can't preface every discussion with your coworkers like this : it gets tiring quickly.

@Astariul but after one or two times you no longer need to preface it :)

While I agree with the comments saying that in the example you give, Bartok sounds quite reasonable and makes efforts to be non-confrontational, I also think there are things you can try to show you're invested in the idea.
The thing about the example conversation, is that depending on how you read (tone, facial expressions, etc...), it can be seen as both side : Bartok trying to understand, or Bartok trying to poke holes.
Bartok can show he's more invested, by showing genuine interest.
Instead of asking a general question (such as "Can you explain the logic ?"), which put the burden of explaining on the other person, Bartok could instead show his own reasoning.
For example :

Arthika: Right, so then we should put the foo in the bar?
Bartók: I'm not following the logic. As far as I remember, all quxes happened because foo was wrongly linked to the baz. But the foo doesn't appear in bar, so I don't think it would help, right ?
Arthika: No, but in bar [...]

I've had multiple similar conversations with coworkers about technical topics, on both sides (being the one not understanding and being the one trying to explain a new idea), and pro-actively trying to explain why you think this idea is not working always led the conversation to a constructive place, as opposed to just saying "I don't get it".
The thing is, when I try to explain a new idea and the other person just say "I don't get it", I have no "entry point" for a constructive conversation. I can simply answer "what is the part you don't understand", which isn't helpful.
But if the other person highlights his understanding of the problem, I can either spot the misunderstanding and correct them, or dive into more details about the thing we are talking about. It's a way to align together on the subject, to ensure we have the same understanding, when usually one person has more domain knowledge than the other.
Similarly, when someone exposes his idea and I don't follow the logic, by exposing my own logic, I prompt the other person to go into finer details, which usually develops into a constructive conversation (i.e. one of us was misunderstanding a piece of the code and the conversation clarifies this misunderstanding)
